# What Pokémon are catchable on Route 1 in Pokémon: Ash Grey?

Tags: pokemon-ash-grey

In Pokémon Ash Grey, The story closely follows that of the Anime, including for example, the situation with Spearow in the very first episode, that formed the close bond between Pikachu and Ash.

The game is fairly similar to the other official games, including random encounters in grass. After getting to Viridian City, you can then re-visit Route 1, to train or capture Pokémon. However, all I've managed to run into so far are Spearow, and one Pidgey (which I caught).

**Are these the only Pokémon in the area?** Or does the game allow all pokemon seen on that route in the Anime to be caught?

<sub>**Note:** In the Anime, there was a Rattatta digging through Ash's bag, as well as a montage of other Pokémon including Mankey whilst Ash was running away from Spearow, and even a Gyarados at one stage when Ash was underwater.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to go ahead and put it to the test. I ran around and battled **100** Pokémon on Route 1, and recorded what they were. Although my sample size was relatively small, I think this gives a good indication of what Pokémon are available.

### Route 1

- **Pidgey**: 36
- **Spearow**: 32
- **Ratatta**: 29
- **Sandshrew**: 3

Comment: Assuming the basic engine is unchanged (which I think is a pretty safe assumption), the encounters are determined from a number of slots attached to each route (each route has the same number of slots). There are two slots with rates of 20, 5, 4 and 1% , and four slots with a rate of 10%. Seeing Sandshrew 3% of the times likely just means it's in one of the last slots.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen - Good point. I've removed the part about Sandshrew.

Comment: You can also run into a Mankey as well, but it is very, very rare.

Answer (score 1):

I found Pidgey, Spearow, Ratatta and Sandshrew. I also found a Mankey.

Answer (score 1):

I sped up the game via an emulator and did 1000000 wild encounters. I was able to encounter Pidgey, Ratatta, Spearow, Sandshrew and Mankey.

There is nothing else in the area.

Comment: How did you test exactly 1 million encounters? If you can show how you tested exactly this much then this answer is a more thorough test than the simple 100 I tested, but without proof it's not much better.